# Change two attribute of html element with animation by css3

Tags: html, css

I want top and box-shadow  attributes execute with animation .I wrote this codes but only box-shadow run with animation.I want my animation executed such as [this](http://hmahdavi.zgig.ir/outline/index.html/#fh5co-pricing).  How to fix this?

```
    .popup {
        -webkit-transition: 1s;
        -moz-transition: 1s;
        -ms-transition: 1s;
        -o-transition: 1s;
        transition: 1s;
    }

    .popup:hover {
            top: -10px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you give us the initial value of 'top' ?

if you use a framework like boostrap, semantic-ui, 
add (!important)

top: -10px important;

Comment: Element has no top attribute . and I use bootstrap. The top attribute changed but with out animation .I want changed with animation

Comment: add an initial value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053552/webkit-transition-for-top-and-bottom-properties

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798939/css-animation-doesnt-work-changing-top-value

Comment: I update my code but don't run animation of top attribute

Comment: add for initial .popup, { position:absolute; top:0; }